# C++ while(cin >> x){} vs. while(true) {cin >>x;}

Tags: c++

Please consider this C++ code for creation and traversing a linked list (number of nodes to be decided by user, not programmer)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Node
{ 
 public:
 int data; Node* next;
 Node(int d, Node* j): data(d),next(j) {cout << "Constructor\n";}
};

int main()
{int n; Node* p; Node* q = 0;

while(cin >> n) 
{ p = new Node(n,q);
  q = p;}

for(;p->next; p=p->next)
    cout << p->data << "->";
    cout << p-> data << "->*\n";
return 0;}
```

The code above works perfectly, and can be terminated by the user using **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>** followed by **<kbd>Enter</kbd>**. However if we replace while(cin >> n) with while (true) using cin >> n; inside the loop, as shown here

```
    while(true) 
    { cin >> n;
    p = new Node(n,q); q = p;}
```

then upon the user attempting to terminate, the loop just goes on automatically creating new Nodes!!  Why??
Thanks in advance

Comment: It goes on because the condition is `true`.

Comment: Let's see if I've got this straight: You tell it to do something forever unconditionally, and then you wonder why it tries to do it forever unconditionally?

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. Jerry, in both cases we tell the loop to go on unconditionally simply because we want the user to have control over termination of node creation at runtime. Both programs use cin within a loop and wait for user input at cin. So why does the behavior of the two programs differ upon attempting termination? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It keeps going because the loop condition is `true`, making it an infinite loop.  If you want to break out of the infinite loop, you can use a `break` statement, e.g.

```
while (true) {
    if (!(cin >> n)) {
        break; // exits the loop
    }
    p = new Node(n,q);
    q = p;
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. Please guide me specifically where I would get to know how cin >> n works when used as a condition rather than as a statement in C++.

Comment: cin is a global variable of type std::istream (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/cin/).  The >> operator of an istream returns an istream reference (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/).  That istream reference has a "logical not" operator which tests the failbit and badbit (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/operatornot/).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps there is a misunderstanding that the code `cin >> n` somehow automatically causes a break out of the loop whenever it hits an end of file. In fact, we either have to check for the end of file implicitly, as shown in the original example or in @MrFooz' solution, or explicitly, as shown below:

```
while(true) { 
    cin >> n;
    if (cin.eof()) break; // We're explicitly checking for EOF here
    p = new Node(n,q);
    q = p;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+D signals EOF, which likely causes the >> operation to return false because the user has signaled the end of stdin.

Comment: Not "likely", it _does_ end stdin.

Comment: I was more unsure about whether or not >> actually returned false.